# Help on a proof involving subsequences

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

> Let $s_n$ be a sequence. Prove that if $\lim_{n\to\infty} s_n = s$ and
>   $s_n$ has a subsequence $s_{n_k}$ such that $(-1)^k s_{n_k} \geq 0$,
>   $s = 0$.

I have no idea where to begin with this one. I know that the subsequence must also be a convergent sequence, but I'm not sure if that's a useful fact to solve this problem.

Comment: Well, since $(-1)^ks_{n_k}≥0$ for all $k$ then there are infinitely many terms in the sequence which are $≥0$ and infinitely many that are $≤0$ so...

Comment: How do you know that your second claim is true?

Comment: Which are you calling my second claim?  If $k$ is even then $s_{n_k}≥0$.  If $k$ is odd then $s_{n_k}≤0$

Comment: Ah, okay, that clears things up. I wasn't sure how you knew that there are infinitely many terms that were less than or equal to 0.

Comment: The wording is misleading. It says that there is A subsequence such that... Not that ALL subsequence of the kind react that way. With the exact wording, there is no such proof (for instance, the $k$ could all be even). With the extended wording, there is a solution already posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $k$ is odd.
Thus, $$s_{n_k}\rightarrow-s\geq0,$$ which says $s\leq0$.

Let $k$ is even.
Thus, $$s_{n_k}\rightarrow s\geq0,$$ which says $s\geq0$.

Comment: How do you define $a_{n_k}$ here?

Comment: @Taliant It's $s_{n_{2k}}$ and $s_{n_{2k-1}}.$ for natural $k$. Both of them converge to $s$.It was typo. I fixed.

Comment: I understand what conclusion I'm supposed to reach, but I don't understand how you justify that $s_{n_k}$ → $-s \geq 0$.

Comment: @Taliant Because if $a_n\geq0$ and there is $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow+\infty}a_n$ then $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow+\infty}a_n\geq0.$ In our case, for example $\lim\limits_{k\rightarrow+\infty}\left((-1)^{2k}s_{n_{2k}}\right)\geq0,$ which gives $s\geq0.$

Comment: How do you know that $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n$ exists here?

Comment: Because there exists $\lim\limits_{k\rightarrow+\infty}s_{n_{2k}}=s.$ Thus, $s\geq0$. Also,  there exists $\lim\limits_{k\rightarrow+\infty}(-s_{n_{2k-1}})=-s.$ Thus, $-s\geq0$.